# python - turn a combination function into a generator

Tags: python, generator

I have a function that creates all combinations of list items, representing this as a list of lists:

```
def makeCombos(arr):
  yield (sum([map(list, combinations(arr, i)) for i in range(len(arr) + 1)], []))
```

Calling `makeCombos([1,2,3,4,5])` gives me a generator object, but calling `.next()` does not give me one combo at a time, it gives me the entire list of combos.

How can I turn this into a generator function that I can call?

Comment: so you want the power set of `arr`?, there is a recipe for that in [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum(iterable, [])` doesn't create a list of lists. It actually flattens things.

`yield (sum(...))` in this line you're just yielding a single item, the flattened list of all combinations.

For Python 2.X `sum([(map(list, combinations(arr, i))) ...])` will work, but in Python 3.X `map` no longer returns a list. Instead it returns a map object. So, if anyones on Python 3.X simply turn this into `list(map(.....))` for this to run on 3.X.

I think what you actually want is something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
def makeCombos(arr):
     for i in range(len(arr) + 1):
         for combo in map(list, combinations(arr, i)):
            yield combo

#Or call next 

combos = makeCombos([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
for combo in combos:
     print combo
```

An alternative from the comment(s) for a one-liner:

Instead of yielding we can *return* a generator object and cycle through just as we would with the `yield`.

e.g. -

```
from itertools import combinations

def makeCombos(arr):

     return (combo for i in range(len(arr) + 1) for combo in map(list, combinations(arr, i)))

combos = makeCombos([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
....
```

As for this being "Pythonic" I wouldn't really say so. I actually prefer the nested forloop it is by far more readable.

Although, we can still try to clean it up some more / compact it by doing a few "tricks"

```
from itertools import combinations as cs #or some other name)

def makeCombos(arr):

    return (c for i in range(len(arr) + 1) for c in map(list, cs(arr, i)))
```

But, now you've lost all readability and this looks like something you'd see in *Perl*. (the horror!)

Output:

```
[]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[2, 5]
[3, 4]
[3, 5]
[4, 5]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: With a name like Pythonista, how can I argue. Haha. One question: Is there a more "pythonic", "one-line" way of stating that nested for loop?

Comment: `def makeCombos(arr): return (combo for i in range(len(arr) + 1) for combo in map(list, combinations(arr, i)))`. Yes, `return`. I.e., turn the double comprehension directly into a generator.

Comment: @alexis isn't this what I have? Not following.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools` already has a method for joining iterables together: it's called `chain`.  What you want is something like the following:

```
def makeCombos(arr):
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(arr, i) for i in range(len(arr) + 1))
```

Simple, short, and fairly Pythonic in my opinion.

Comment: instead of creating a list, better use `chain.from_iterable`

Comment: @Atsch I believe the question was asking for combinations, not permutations.  I don't see how permutations would help here